# How to get a "zoomed out" code view in Visual Studio?

Tags: sublime-text-2, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, komodo-ide

Sublime Text and Komodo IDE both have a very neat feature where you have a preview of the entire file you are working on in a "zoomed out" view that you can scrub up and down to move around your code.

Does anyone know if there is a way or an extension for Visual Studio to have a similar style preview?

Sublime Text: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/img/prefixr/after.png

Komodo IDE: http://community.activestate.com/files/images/window_editor_openfiles_minimap_toolbar.preview.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) offers and Enhanced Scrollbar feature along with many others.  Also, when hovering over a section of the scroll bar, it also displays a snippet of that code that corresponds with your cursor position (shown below).

[image: Enhanced Scrollbar]

Answer (score 6):

Starting PowerTools 2013 you will not find this feature. Because it is integrated in VS. For activating this: right-click on the scrollbar -> scrollbar options... ->behavior -> use map mode.
Works also with VS2015

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio (March 2019) 1.33 you can do this:

```
View --> Toggle Minimap
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.